# Function for calculating pre-set commissions within Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a function for calculating a pre-set commission within google sheets. I keep on getting a syntax error for line 15.

Can anyone help me? There is a description of what I am trying to achieve commented on the top.

```js
/**Calculates commission based on the following rules
if less than 33 subtract 3
if in between 33.01 and 55 subtract 5
if in between 55.01 and 100 subtract 10
if more than or equal to 100 multiply by .9

*/

function comS(input) {

 if (input <= 33) {
  return (input - 3);
 } 
 else if (input >= 33.01 && <= 55) {
  return (input - 5);
 }  
 else if (input >= 55.01 && <= 100) {
  return (input * 0.9);
 } else {
            return "Please insert a valid amount"
    }
}


/**
End of function
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `&&` operators work, you need to set the comparison on each side:

`(input >= 55.01 && input <= 100)`